# How Make a 2d cube via css

Tags: css

i want have an animation like this:
i want one Square fade in a place holder like code below

```
#item1_placeholder{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 7%;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 7%; 
                                    border: 3px solid #F4DC03;
```

}

and i want this placeholder and cube resize with resizing display window,

then this Square rotate like a 2d cube in some direction like first show the front, then turn to left, then turn to top

can anyone help me!!!

Comment: dont you mean 3d cube...as there is no depth in 2d

Answer (score 0):

[Check THIS](https://davidwalsh.name/css-cube)

play around with the css how you like to make the cube

Answer (score 0):

first i must Apology for my bad English, i made it like this below code:

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    body {
                font-family:'BebasRegular';
                text-align:center;
                background-color: #d0d2d0;
                background-image:url(../Image/Back_pattern.png);    
                width: 95%;
                height: 95%;
                margin:auto;
                }

    div#main {
                font-size: 3vw;
                }

    #content {
                        margin:auto;
                        height:100vh;
                        width:100vw;
                    }
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasRegular';
    src: url('../Fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../Fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../Fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../Fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../Fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.svg#BebasRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
#item1_placeholder{
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 7%;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: 7%;
}


  #AHCube div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 7vw;
    height: 7vw;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
  }

  #AHCube .Front { 
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(3.5vw);
  transform: translateZ(3.5vw);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(3.5vw);
  -o-transform: translateZ(3.5vw);
  }
  #AHCube .Right {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);                  
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);                  
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);       
  -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);                             
  }
  #AHCube .Top {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);  
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);  
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);  
  -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);  
  }
  #AHCube .Back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);
  }
  #AHCube .Left { 
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw); 
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw); 
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw); 
  -o-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(3.5vw); 
  }
  #AHCube .Below { 
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);      
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);      
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);      
  -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(3.5vw);      
  background:rgba(3,76,244,1.00);
}



  .AH_Ani1 {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 3.5vw 3.5vw 0;

    animation-name: spin1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: 3.5vw 3.5vw 0;

    -moz-animation-name: spin1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-origin: 3.5vw 3.5vw 0;  

    -o-animation-name: spin1;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-animation-duration: 5s;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-origin: 3.5vw 3.5vw 0;  
    }
    .ICO_Hold1 {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        filter: drop-shadow(5% 5% 5% #222);
        width: 80%;
        height: auto;
        display:block;
  }



  @-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
    from,to  { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
    0% { -webkit-transform:scale(0,0);      }    
    10% { -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);     }  
    28%      { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);                           }
    46%      { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);            }
    64%      { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);           }
    82%      { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);             }
    100%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);                            }
  }
  @keyframes spin1 {
    from,to  { transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
    0% { transform:scale(0,0);      }    
    10% { transform:scale(1,1);     }  
    28%      { transform: rotateY(-90deg);                           }
    46%      { transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);            }
    64%      { transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);           }
    82%      { transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);             }
    100%      { transform: rotateX(90deg);                            }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes spin1 {
    from,to  { -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
    0% { -moz-transform:scale(0,0);     }    
    10% { -moz-transform:scale(1,1);        }  
    28%      { -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);                           }
    46%      { -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);            }
    64%      { -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);           }
    82%      { -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);             }
    100%      { -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);                            }
  }
  @-o-keyframes spin1 {
    from,to  { -o-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
    0% { -o-transform:scale(0,0);       }    
    10% { -o-transform:scale(1,1);      }  
    28%      { -o-transform: rotateY(-90deg);                           }
    46%      { -o-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);            }
    64%      { -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);           }
    82%      { -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);             }
    100%      { -o-transform: rotateX(90deg);                            }
  }  


}




@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {

#item1_placeholder{
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 0%;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: 0%; 
}
  #AHCube div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0vw;
    height: 0vw;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
  }
    .ICO_Hold1 {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(50% 50% 50% #222 );
        filter: drop-shadow(5% 5% 5% #222);
        width: 0%;
        height: auto;
        display:none;
  }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="item1_placeholder" >

<div id="AHCube" class="AH_Ani1">
<div class="Front"><img class="ICO_Hold1" src="Image/1-1.png" /></div>
<div class="Right"><img class="ICO_Hold1" src="Image/1-2.png" /></div>
<div class="Top"><img class="ICO_Hold1" src="Image/1-3.png" /></div>
<div class="Back"><img class="ICO_Hold1" src="Image/1-4.png"  /></div>
<div class="Left"><img class="ICO_Hold1" src="Image/1-5.png" /></div>
<div class="Below"><img class="ICO_Hold1" src="Image/1-6.png" /></div>

</div>

</div>
```

it work fine in chrome and Mozilla but it is not fine IE or Microsoft Edge, and i didn't check it in portable device

can any one check this and hint me to correct this?